# populating an xml from user defined values in java

Tags: java, xml, user-defined

My requirement is that I have a number of XML templates and depending on certain decision params, I have to populate it either with values given by user or from a property file. The XMLs are quite long and nested. I understand any of the following approaches need to be taken for the solution:

1). First unmarshall the xml into a java object >> populate the object from user/property file >> again marshall the resulting object to get the final xml.
2). search for the pattern of tags and replace it with the given values.

I believe former approach is better since it Object oriented and less errorneous, though it will be a big task to populate each and every instance variable of the object.

Also that the latter may result in a cumbersome code as well as lots of errors as pattern may be different : for e.g.,

```
 > <maven></maven>

 or <maven />.
```

> My question is, is there any other promising and faster approach that
>   can be taken to achieve this?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: a quick google will give you several libraries that can parse the xml for you, you can even generate the java classes from xml online, example: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/ (google first result for 'xml to java online')

Comment: That is again the first approach ...right?

Comment: yes, I would go for that one, normally it should make the code more readable and easier to maintain. You can change the tags values as well, but out of the box I find it more complicated (even though it might be less code)

Answer (score 0):

You might use xpath for extracting xml tags.

[How to read XML using XPath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811001/how-to-read-xml-using-xpath-in-java)

Also it should be tried to see if it is faster.